# Music player for my raspberry pi2

Tags: pi-2

Is there a easy to use music player for a raspberry pi 2? I tried to download one on Google play, but all it did was highlight the install button. going to youtube and searching all the time takes a long time on my raspberry pi.

Comment: Hello and welcome – Which OS? Are you using android (because you said "Google play")? Are you using Raspbian lite or desktop with GUI?

Comment: It is not clear if you want to press the buttons on your smart phone screen, and BlueTooth to Rpi which controls a MIDI music player. Of course your smart phone alone or Rpi alone can also play low quality "software" music.  But if you want HiFi music, you might need MIDI. You might like to search "MIDI" in this forum, or try this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98016/use-pi-as-a-midi-controller-input. Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01 Why are you talking about MIDI? The question doesn't mention or even allude to MIDI.

Comment: @Mark Smith, Thank you for your good question.  It is a bit hard to use my broken English to answer.  It would be nice if others can help, before me struggling. PS - I always bear in mind the StackOverflow's policy "We prefer laser sharp focus on a subject ..."

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=188723 or https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=139983

Comment: @Dougie, your comment hinted I might misunderstand the OP about "music player".  In my daily Cantonese conversation, we say "mp3 player".  If we talk about a physical thing, we would say "musical instrument". In Arduino forums, I would ask "What do you mean by by "music player", do you mean "mp3 player"?  If the OP clarifies that he wants  mp3/mp4 media player, then I would recommend "smart phone BlueTooth connect to Rpi buster VLC player".  Sometimes my comment to clarify OP's question is often not replied, so I gave an umbrella answer including MIDI, the kitchen sink! :)