# How do I connect a MIDI socket to the GPIO pins on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio, midi

I have a *Raspberry Pi 4 model B* and a five pin MIDI connector ([PRT-09536](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/SparkFun/PRT-09536?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvShe%252BZiYheisenuOfF2S5lD2qyKZySYZ4%3D)). The female MIDI jack is circular and has five holes on the front, and seven pins on the bottom. Five pins are staggered in the back and there are two closer to the front.

How do I get the device to communicate using that part? What GPIO pins on the Pi should be connected to which pins on the jack?

Do I need to install any software to get it to work?

I'm probably going to install [Ubuntu 20 server](https://ubuntu.com/raspberry-pi/server). I think I know how to flash the OS and everything, just including that detail in case it changes anything.

Comment: https://www.samplerbox.org/article/midiinwithrpi or https://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry+pi+gpio+midi+socket&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS906US906&oq=raspberry+pi+gpio+midi+socket&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3j69i60.8357j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Ah, you can use uart port to talk to a midi controller. See the wiring by my answer to the following Q&A: Use Pi as a MIDI Controller Input Asked 2 years, 9 months ago Active 2 months ago Viewed 722 times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98016/use-pi-as-a-midi-controller-input/98026#98026

Comment: did you want midi in or out? as for 7 pin midi jack ... never heard of it - I think they are 5 pin

Comment: @Bravo The 5-pin jack has two additional connections for the shield and for mechanical reasons.

Comment: @CL. some do maybe